# Siiloxane polymer experiment

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, halides, organometallic-compounds, organosilicon-compounds

[image: Silane reaction]

I believe the first reaction would be a substitution of $\ce{SiMe3}$ for $\ce{I}$ and creating $\ce{SiMe3Cl}$.

The second process I think would involve the $\ce{Mg}$ removing the two $\ce{Cl}$ and forming diphenylsilane, which would likely be a repeating unit in a silicone polymer.

Could any explain the mechanism for these reactions?

Comment: You are correct about reaction 1, but I have yet to see a mechanism for this

Comment: @Waylander Wouldn't the first reaction just be an $\mathrm{S_E Ar}$ ?

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti  maybe, but I would like to see a reference that says so

Answer (score -3):

A)SiMe3 Increases the inductivity and reduces Aromaticity,

so by free radical (uv termination) its likely to have p-iodideSi(Me)3Bencene.

[image]

B)Dimer crystal solution in Cl- ions.  (Ph)2Si(Cl)Mg+---ClSi(Ph)2

Or Solid crystals of (Ph)2Si(Cl)MgCl.
[image]

Comment: Er no. ICl iodinates with desilylation in the presence of silver salts http://www.xiuzhengrd.com/ejournals/pdf/synthesis/doi/10.1055/s-1993-25912.pdf